# 3-axis chart (Z-axis) possible with TeeChart?? Any tutorials to be found on subject?

Tags: vcl, teechart

I am trying to create a 'TRENDS' chart.

For that, I am trying to create a 3-D bar chart with left axis (Y-axis) being a number scale (like 0-1000), Bottom axis (X-axis) to be 7 days (Mon-Sun), and depth axis (Z-axis) to be weeks. My report data spans back to 11/2/12 and has data (a single number) for each day. So, basically the graph should have a scale of 0-1000 on the left, 7 labels along the horizontal (Mon-Sun), and then approx 36 rows deep (Z-axis) containing the data (bar for EACH day) with a 'row' label for that week (eg. xx/xx/13 to xx/xx/13).

Step by step instructions for TeeCharts are scarce to start AND I have found nothing on the Net describing how to do a Z-axis (3rd axis). Am I trying to use the TeeChart software to create a chart it is NOT capable of delivering??

Example 3d layout on page 12: http://www.nrdc.org/air/pollution/benchmarking/2002/benchmark2002_pt2.pdf

PLEASE, any input would be welcome. Thanks.

Mike

Comment: Mike, which TeeChart version are you using? Please add the platform tag to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you posted [the same question](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=90745&tstart=0) at the [Embarcadero Forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/index.jspa?categoryID=1), I assume you are using TeeChart VCL/FMX. Having this in mind, you can achieve what you request with TeeChart Pro version. You can see the differences between TeeChart versions in this [feature matrix](http://www.steema.com/featurematrix/vcl).

To plot this kind of charts you should use Tower series. You'll find examples at the *"All Features\Welcome !\Chart styles\Extended\Tower*" section in the new features demo included with both evaluation and registered versions. Fully functional evaluation version can be downloaded [here](http://www.steema.com/download/vcl).

Also, bear in mind that 3D series like Tower series need to be populated as I explained [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5312).

Comment: Narcis, thnak you so much for your info. I use D2010 and TeeChart Pro (I think). The component palette has 2 tabs (TeeChart & TeeTree) and the first tabs has 32 icons/comps. Sorry I cant be more specific. My worksation has D7 and D2007 on it and I have now inherited another users machine whixh has D2010 on it.

Comment: I looked at both your links and have 2 questions.. what is the z-axis feature called? I can't see where Delphi (included TC version) version differs from Pro version for purposes of 3-axis chart. I read your 2nd link but am wondering if I can just hand input data for z-axis with chart editor like I do with the other 2 axis. Ultimately I will have to populate the chart via query results from a DB2 db [for my client] but for now I just need to get them a prototype chart to view and approve on this coming Tues.

Comment: @user2659036 We call z-axis, "depth axis". The Pro version contains such 3D chart styles, the Standard version doesn't. Yes, you can populate 3D charts manually too.